# Reconstruct PIE executable with true runtime addresses from perf.data

Tags: linux, perf

Essentially I am looking for a way to get the output of `perf annotate` but instead of with `objdump`, **with the true addresses from runtime**.

`perf script` with `-F +brstack` will get pretty close in that it will be reconstruct the control flow from a sampling period with the true addresses, but so far I haven't been able to find a way to get perf to organize it into an `objdump` like format (but with the true addresses).

`perf record` does seem to reconstruct a coherent binary but ends up using `perf annotate`/`objdump` and doesn't seem to display the true addresses.

**Is there any way to get one of the `perf` tools or some other tool to do this?**

NOTE: I am running an out of the box ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.11